# I want to format 2nd column in the query to return numerical values with 2 decimals places. The problem is all the rows return: {100.00,100.00,100.00}

Tags: arrays, postgresql

This is the snippet of code. It runs well, the issue is it returns 100.00 for each value and not actual decimal figures like say 68.73 for example

```
select 

array(select products.product_category_name from brooklyndata.olist_products_dataset order by orders_and_revenue.revenue desc limit 3) as top_three_product_categories_by_revenue

, array(select round(cast(sum(orders_and_revenue.revenue) over (partition by products.product_category_name) as decimal)/round(cast(sum(orders_and_revenue.revenue) over () as decimal)) * 100,2) from brooklyndata.olist_products_dataset order by orders_and_revenue.revenue desc limit 3 )

, orders_and_revenue.revenue 
from brooklyndata.olist_products_dataset as products
```

Comment: If I am following correctly I believe you need another set of brackets: `round((cast ... as decimal)) * 100, 2)`. I would also suggest running the query through [pgFormatter](https://sqlformat.darold.net/) to make it easier to read.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver do you mean another set of brackets for the denominator?

Comment: No for the whole  fraction. I showed you the relevant portions, insert the new brackets I added at the places indicated.